# Options Pattern and User Secrets (Asp Core 2.2.)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I want to access my project´s user secrets with the options pattern. But when I use the options pattern the secret values is null; but my other configurations options work well.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettingsData>(Configuration);        
    services.Configure<MyUserSecrets>(Configuration);
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
MyController(    
    IOptionsMonitor<MyUserSecrets> myUserSecrets
){
    _mySecrets = myUserSecrest.CurrentValue;
}
```

According to the documents I should add AddUserSecrets to builder, my builder look different from the example code. Here us my builder:

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args);
builder.add // No AddUserSecrest available...
builder.Build().Run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the subsections from appsettings the option need to ask the configuration to get the section.

```
services.Configure<AppSettingsData>(Configuration); 
services.Configure<MyUserSecrets>(Configuration.GetSection("MyUserSecrets"));
```

Comment: I can agree that using the Configuration.GetSection etc works for looking up values that are in usersecrets